# How to make entries of Gravity Forms available in the public front-end?

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I want to make entries of the Gravity Forms available for the public in the front-end. I read in a forum post that this is [possible](http://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/view-form-content-on-public-front-end-page-of-site#post-17323) with some specific free add-on for Gravity Forms. But I couldn't find it.

Do you know the name of that add-on or do you know an easy to implement method to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Gravity Forms + Custom Post Types: Allows a simple way to map a Gravity Form post entry to a custom post type. Also include custom taxonomies.

I think this might be what you are looking for. In my WP plugin list  I see Gravity Form and Gravity Forms + Custom Post Types as two separate plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment - I just can't post them yet...but Melanie's Answer is the correct one.

Keep in mind that gravity forms has nothing to do with the custom post type - you will have to create that yourself either via code or with a plugin.

To make a form entry post to a custom post type - from the Post Fields field types, add a "Post Title" field to your form.  In the Properties tab of this field, you can set the initial status and a category for the added post.  In the Advanced tab, you can set the post type to use (but only if the plugin Melanie mentioned is installed and activated).

And then...of course...you will have to handle displaying the custom post type posts on your blog...

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

to display the data entered through gravity from you need to use gravity form directory plugin

the url is [click](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-addons/)

Comment: Please see the [faq] about writing good answers.